# Linking specific asp RequiredFieldValidators to specific asp buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a ASP.NET page. Which has 3 buttons. 
Button1 should do a post-back once dateinput1, dateinput2 are validated.
Button2 should do a ajax call to its onclick event once textbox1 is validated.
Button3 should do a ajax call to its onclick even once textbox2 is validated.

Now what I did was placed the asp:RequiredFieldValidator and linked them the controls they need to validate.

Now whats happening is when I click Button1, it is also checking for validation of textbox1 and textbox2. Which it should not do. How do I do this??

Thanks in advance.

regards
Yash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign different [ValidationGroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx) to your controls.